# How align button and input in twig using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I render button and one input on my view. Input have label, so button is rendered at the same height as label. I would like input and button in the same line.
[image]

How can I do this?
It's my view, where I generate form:

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'novalidate':'novalidate'}}) }}
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-5">
             {{ form_row(form.name)}}
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-2">
             {{ form_row(form.add) }}
         </div>
    </div>
 {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways to do it.
1. If your design allows, you can use `inline-form` class to produce inline form.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

2. You can use input with button

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">        
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: I have shown the final 'html' output, you have to code it in ur view specific scripting language

Comment: On first solution, you hide the label, on second: button is render in new line.

Comment: @PawełBrzoski I guess you have not tested the above code. Also look at the [bootstrap online doc](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons) under the button addon section, then you would have clear idea.